# Array of type protocol in swift

Tags: swift

What is best way in swift to get objects of specific type.
e.g

```
protocol Fruit {
    func setColor()

}

class Orange:NSObject, Fruit {
    func setColor() {

    }
}

class Apple:NSObject, Fruit {
    func setColor() {
    }
}


class MyClass {

    var fruits:[Fruit]? // get from data base

    //here how to get fruits only of type Orange. i.e. Array of oranges

}
```

Here one way is I can put "for in" loop and check type of each object and then can add it in new array.

But is there any other swifty way to do?

EDIT:

Below works for me. Is there any other way to do?

```
  var oranges: [Orange] = []
   for orange in fruits {

   if let myOrange = orange as? Orange {
        oranges.append(myOrange)
     }
   }
```

Comment: It's bad practice to write setters and getters in Swift. Just use public properties. That's what they're there for.

Comment: Also no need to subclass NSObject unless you are planning to conform it to NSCoding otherwise you should use structs instead of classes.

Comment: bad naming for the loop, would be much better for `fruit in fruits` and then `if let orange = fruit as? Orange {`

Comment: btw just add a computed property to MyClass `var oranges: [Orange] {
        return fruits.flatMap{$0 as? Orange} }`

Comment: Java is bad for a reason... setters and getters make NO SENSE 99% of the time... it's just extra work for you so you have the feeling of 'encapsulation safety' but really it's not doing a thing for your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to iterate over these in a `for` loop, just add a `where` clause:

```
for fruit in fruits where fruit is Orange {

}
```

If you want a filtered array (still of type `[Fruit]`) to store for future use, use `filter`:

```
let oranges = fruits.filter{ $0 is Orange }
```

If you want a filtere array (of type `[Orange]`) to store for future use, user `flatMap`:

```
let oranges = fruits.flatMap{ $0 as? Orange }
```

Comment: I am getting error for filter option - Cannot convert value of type '[Fruit]' to expected argument type '[Orange]'

Comment: @user364765 Did you unwrap fruits?

Comment: `let oranges = fruits.flatMap { $0 as? Orange }`

Comment: @user3647675 Oh yeah, if you want to get an `[Orange]` back, you'll need to actually do the cast, as vacawama suggests.

Comment: @user3647675 can you update your code now to show the new error and such?